# Receive notiifcation for Email / SMS

Tags: iphone, android, ios4, blackberry

Can i get notifications in my app when receiving SMS / Email on the devices such as iphone / android / blackberry? Also can i able to send / Receive SMS form my app on these devices (iphone / android / blackberry)

Please guide me out...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Android:send and receive, windows phone 7:only send

Answer (score 1):

There is no default E-mail client on Android, so it will depend on the e-mail client that the users uses. SMS on Android will not be a problem.

On iOS you can only send SMS/E-mail there is no way to check for any received SMS/E-mails.

Blackberry, not sure.

Windows phone 7, same as the iPhone send only.

Answer (score 1):

On Blackberry for SMS, you can see the article [Different ways to listen for SMS messages](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0) for info on receiving SMS and the [SMS class javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/sms/SMS.html) for info on listening for outgoing messages.  You will probably also find the article [Sending and receiving GSM SMS on Blackberry](http://myhowto.org/java/j2me/22-sending-and-receiving-gsm-sms-on-blackberry-using-rim-apis/) useful.

For email, you should probably start with the article [Add a listener to a folder](http://docs.blackberry.com/tr-tr/developers/deliverables/17953/Add_listener_to_folder_565436_11.jsp) and then dive into [the javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/event/EventListener.html).